# Cross-Origin Read Blocking for steam market api

Tags: javascript, json, steam-web-api

I'm trying to make an js app that gets the price of the Steam's "Sack of Gems" on their comunity market.

I need to download / parse the JSON in https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=0&appid=753&market_hash_name=753-Sack%20of%20Gems .

I tried jquery's $.getJSON, fully-js JSONP, and more.

full js JSONP:

```
<script>
function getJSONP(url, success) {
     var ud = '_' + +new Date,
          script = document.createElement('script'),
          head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
               || document.documentElement;

     window[ud] = function(data) {
          head.removeChild(script);
          success && success(data);
     };

     script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
     head.appendChild(script);
}

function button () {
     alert('Start!');
     getJSONP('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=0&appid=753&market_hash_name=753-Sack%20of%20Gems&callback=?', function(data){
     console.log(data);
     });  
}

</script>
```

I'm always getting this error:

`steam_gem_calculator.html:100 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=0&appid=753&market_hash_name=753-Sack%20of%20Gems&callback=_1569097351408 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

but i want the data to be logged in the console.

EDIT: Is it possible because i'm testing by viewing the file?

Comment: Try receiving it as JSON not JSONP

Comment: i did that first.

Comment: Most probably it's no programming problem but a problem with your browser settings!

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions:

1. use proxy
2. install an extension to your browser that allow access origin; I suggest you [cors everywhere extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) (for short time solution)